# npm start fails with events.js:174 throw err; on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, ubuntu-18.04

I have been trying to get the basic electron-quick-start demo working on Ubuntu 18.04. Everything works up to the point that I try:  `npm start` at which point I get this error:

```
> electron .

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /home/me/docs/electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron/dist/electron EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I have tried clearing the npm cache, rebooting, and nothing seems to work.

There seem to be two versions of node.js installed:

```
node -v ==> v10.15.3
nodejs -v ==> v11.15.0
```

Both these versions are probably the result of trying to upgrade node.js to a newer version than what comes with Ubuntu, though I don't know why or how. I upgraded following the instructions on this webpage - https://github.com/nodesource/distributions:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

When that didn't work I tried again with vers 11.x.

My version of npm is:  `6.9.0`

Why are there two versions of `node.js`? Could this be the problem?
What should I do to get `npm start` to work? If clearing everything and starting over is the best approach, I am all for it. This is my first time using node.js, so I am totally lost here. BTW, downloaded electron apps (e.g. VS Code) seem to be working just fine if that's any help.

Comment: Can you say _what_ you ran before running `electron .`? Also, I can strongly recommend removing the various versions of `node`, installing `nvm` and `npx` globally, followed by _never installing anything else globally_ (`nvm` so you can have multiple node versions that you can toggle between, and `npx` so you can run locally installed dependencies. Like electron)

Answer (score 0):

- Solution 1: Try to find the exacly npm/node version your project are using to install.
  Better use a npm version manager like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).
- Solution 2: On linux bash execute:

  ```
  sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
  sudo sysctl -p
  ```
- The reason?
  the OS have a max handle files count. You need to increase this.
- Why?
  did you realize how many files the node_modules folder has on the smallest/simplest project you have? Now, try to imagine on medium/large project.